# Make my IDE recognize methods in my logback.groovy

Tags: groovy, logback

I'm writing my `logback.groovy` file in Eclipse. I've read online that all the dependencies will be pulled in automatically when it runs, which is great, but it's a little frustrating that Eclipse doesn't recognize any of this syntax.

Basically Eclipse is giving all of this code its "I don't know what this is but I trust you" underline. Is there anything I can import to fix this?

```
appender("Console-Appender", ConsoleAppender){
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder){
        pattern = "%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n"
}
```

}

Additionally, does this have to be a script? Or can it be a class called logback that has a `run()` method? I ask because I'd like to be able to get the log path through dependency injection which would work more cleanly on a class.

Comment: Very good question.

Comment: Thanks Rene for your answer. To answer the second part of my question, no it doesn't have to be a script, it can be a class. But it seems like there's no reason for it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy-Eclipse has [DSLDs](https://spring.io/blog/2011/05/09/better-dsl-support-in-groovy-eclipse) (DSL descriptors) since 2011.

Have a look [here](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/tree/master/base/org.codehaus.groovy24/plugin_dsld_support) for the ones it ships with. There is also a [DSLD examples](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/DSLD-examples) wiki page.

With DSLDs Eclipse can be extended to support internal Groovy DSLs like the Logback one.

I am not aware of a DSLD file for Logback. You could write one yourself using Logback's documentation for the [Groovy feature](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html).